# Regular Expression VBA for multiple rows/table?

Tags: excel, expression, vba

I have a text (already stored in a String variable, if you want).
The text is structured as follows:

( 124314 ) GSK67SJ/11 ADS SDK

blah blah blah blah blah

blah blah blah

blah blah blah

( 298 ) 2KEER/98 EOR PRT

blah blah blah

blah blah blah blah blah

etc.

- The number of empty spaces between the words is variable;
- The value in brackets is variable, as the length of the alphanumeric
  group    (this one ends always with "/" and then two numbers);
- The text "blah blah" at the end can be divided in an unknown number
  of lines, each    one with a variable number of characters
- The last two groups of letters are always of 3 letters each. After
  those there is a "/n" immediately after, without spaces;
- The list goes down for 0 to N elements.

For each of them I have to store the number, the first 3-letters, the second 3-letters, and the "blah blah" in 4 columns of an Excel file.
Let's say that the columns are A, B, C, D. The result should be as follow (from A1):

124314 | ADS | SDK | blah blah blah.....

298 | EOR | PRT | blah blah.....

.........

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it

```
    Dim RegX As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp 'Rememeber to reference it...
Dim Mats As Object
Dim TextFiltered As String
Dim counter As Integer

Set RegX = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

With RegX
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "[\s]{2,}(?!\(\s+(\d+)\s+\))" 'This will clear the annoying splitting into different lines of the "blah blah" A PART for the ones before "( number )"
    TextFiltered = .Replace(TextFiltered, " ") ' You could also write [\r\n] instead of [\s] but in that way you eliminate all the spaces in one hit
End With

With RegX 'This is the pattern you're looking for, the brackets mean different elements you could retrieve from the array of the results
    .Pattern = "\(\s+(\d+)\s+\)(\s+\w+/[0-9]{2}\s+)([A-Z]{3})\s+([A-Z]{3})\s+(.+)" 'I think you can remove the "+" from the "\s"
    Set Mats = .Execute(TextFiltered)
End With

For counter = 0 To Mats.Count - 1 'SubMatches is what will give you the various elements one by one (124314, ADS, SDK, etc)
    MsgBox Mats(counter).SubMatches(0) & " " & Mats(counter).SubMatches(2) & " " & Mats(counter).SubMatches(3) & " " & Mats(counter).SubMatches(4) 
Next
```